# Display Users without Posts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I query my Users who have yet to write any posts?
This is what I am trying:

```
u = User.joins(:posts).where('posts.size = ?', 0)
```

Output:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column posts.size does not exist
```

Trying to wrap my head around the correct SQL syntax, but no luck so far

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ***must*** do this without a join, like this:

```
 User.where(Post.where("posts.user_id = users.id").exists.not)
```

Its very useful to chain conditions (like applying different filters).

---

creates SQL like:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  
WHERE (
  NOT (
    EXISTS (SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE (posts.user_id = users.id))
  )
)
```

Comment: it creates an `EXIST` subquery, which is valid sql (and very convenient :) )

Comment: Won't this make two separate SQL requests? Isn't there a way to do it with one?

Comment: @GeorgeMillo it does only one, check the generated sql